# NetBeans terminal window is gray and won't accept characters

Tags: netbeans, terminal-emulator

I am running NetBeans 8.0.2 on a 64-bit Windows 7 PC. I was trying to follow [Geertjan Wielenga's instructions](https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/get_started_with_scala_in) for getting up and running with Scala in NetBeans 8.x.

The first instruction starts, "In the Terminal window, ..." so I selected `Window > IDE Tools > Terminal`. Instead of being a useable terminal window, the tab's content area was completely gray. I noticed that there seemed to be text flashing in the window before it went gray, so I clicked on the "Create New Local Terminal Tab" button multiple times until I was able to read the disappearing text:

`Unable to start pty process`

Searching for this phrase yielded results for C/C++ projects and the "Run" command, but I'm not doing a C/C++ project. How can I get the terminal window to a state where I can interact with it?

Comment: Self answered because I eventually found the answer, but it was hidden in a bug report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The NetBeans Terminal Emulator requires Cygwin. Importantly, the bitness of NetBeans must match the bitness of Cygwin. If you are using a 64-bit version of NetBeans, then you must use a 64-bit version of Cygwin; likewise 32-bit and 32-bit.

This [comment by Andrew Krazny on NetBeans bug 234221](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=234221#c6) says:

> A bitness of jdk/netbeans is important. Possible options are:
>
> 1. 32-bit NB and only 32-bit cygwin is installed
> 2. 32-bit NB and only 64-bit cygwin is installed
> 3. 32-bit NB and both 32/64-bit cygwin are installed
> 4. 64-bit NB and only 32-cygwin is installed
> 5. 64-bit NB and only 64-cygwin is installed
> 6. 64-bit NB and both 32/64-bit cygwin are installed
>
> Cases 1) and 5) are 'ideal' - in this case everything should work and it is *highly recommended* that bitness of NB/cygwin match. This means that if one tries to use cygwin64 (s)he *should* install 64-bit java and run 64-bit version of NetBeans (netbeans64.exe).
>
> Case 2) is almost nonfunctional. It requires cygwin64/bin to be in %Path%; compilation will work, but run is possible in 'External Terminal' only.
>
> Case 3) NB will detect 32-bit cygwin and will use it by default. IF user tries to add cygwin64 as a toolchain and compile his code in 64-mode, run in 'Output Window' will not work. 32-bit toolchain is OK in this case
>
> Case 4) is almost nonfunctional. It requires cygwin/bin to be in %Path%; compilation will work, but run is possible in 'External Terminal' only.
>
> Case 6) 64-bit compilation/run will work, 32-bit run will fail.

In my case, I was using 32-bit Cygwin with 64-bit NetBeans. I installed 64-bit Cygwin, added a `CYGWIN_HOME` environment variable, and added `%CYGWIN_HOME%\bin` to the end of my path¹, and now I have a functioning terminal window.

¹which I hate doing because there are command names that overlap